# PHP strtotime returns incorrect month

Tags: php, strtotime

Don't understand this.

Today is March 30, 2017

```
echo date('n', strtotime("-1 months")); // = 3  ...shouldn't it return 2?
echo date('n', strtotime("-2 months")); // = 1  ...correct 
echo date('n', strtotime("-3 months")); // = 12 ...correct
```

Why am I getting the current month of March for the first line?

Comment: Confirmed on `7.0.17`